# How to keep cell's content on screen while scrolling until the cell runs out of available space?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

The questions itself does not say much, but what I am trying to say is: how can one move the cell's content (let say a `UILabel`), so the label can be seen on screen while the collection view is being scrolled, until the collectionView's cell runs out of available space.

But, a picture is worth a thousand words:

I have something like this, a `UICollectionViewCell` with horizontal scroll.
[image: simulator capture]

Normally, when I scroll this is what it will happen:
[image: simulator capture]

But, what I would like to achieve is the names in the firsts cells to scroll to the right while there is space available in the cell, without forgetting that when there's no more space available it will start to truncate the tail, like: `Keaton Pickett` -> `Keaton Pick...` -> `Keaton...` -> etc,

I've been thinking about nesting the cell's content inside a `UIScrollView` and then scroll it by code when the collectionView scrolls.

I also thought changing the `CGRect` property of the cell's contents (in this case, the `UILabel`) while the view is scrolling (playing with the `width` and `minX` properties.

However, detecting when the, in this case, `UILabel` is starting to be out of the screen (like `Kea` in the first cell of the second picture) is turning to be a struggle.

In my real case scenario I have the `UICollectionView` (horizontal scroll) nested in `UITableView` (vertical scroll).

I will thank and appreciate your help in this predicament.
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use the code

**Objective C**

```
   - (void)checkVisibilityOfCell:(MyCustomUITableViewCell *)cell inScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
        CGRect cellRect = [aScrollView convertRect:cell.frame toView:aScrollView.superview];

        if (CGRectContainsRect(aScrollView.frame, cellRect))
            [cell notifyCompletelyVisible];
           [cells objectAtIndex:i].hidden= YES; // MAKE THE CELL VISIBLE 
        else
            [cell notifyNotCompletelyVisible];
           [cells objectAtIndex:i].hidden= NO;   // MAKE THE CELL UNVISIBLE 
    }

    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView { 
        NSArray* cells = myTableView.visibleCells;

        NSUInteger cellCount = [cells count];
        if (cellCount == 0)
            return;

        // Loop through All  cells
        for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < cellCount - 1; i++)
            [[cells objectAtIndex:i] notifyCompletelyVisible];

    }
```